# could you reveal the identity of this "this"?

Tags: c#

Right after I had added "button control" in the Form1, I got these codes in Form1.Desiner.cs automatically.

```
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(78, 49);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(113, 41);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "button1";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

now I am starting to wondering what's the true identity of "this".
so I tried to replace it (line 4) with

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1.TabIndex = 0;
```

or

```
System.Windows.Forms.Button Form1.button1.TabIndex = 0;
```

but I got following error message which I don't understand.

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, Form1.Desiner.cs method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1'
```

so please tell me how can I replace "this" proper way? (of course it's purpose is for understanding)

Comment: You can't replace `this` with anything. Why do you even want to?

Comment: Why do you want to change generated code? I'll get replaced when you change your form again anyway.

Comment: `this` is the current object instance. In the case above it is the current instance of `Form1` or whatever you named it.  It would be `Me` in VB.NET

Comment: oh good to know `this` was the current object instance. because `this` has many uses.

Comment: `this` has roughly five uses: to disambiguate a parameter name from a local member, to pass the instance to another method, to call a constructor overload from another constructor, to declare an indexer, and to create an extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is a reference to *the current object.*

Assuming that `this` is working properly now, and that `this` isn't there to disambiguate some other identifier (like a local variable or parameter), you can *simply remove `this`*, and the code should still work.

```
button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(78, 49);
button1.Name = "button1";
button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(113, 41);
button1.TabIndex = 0;
button1.Text = "button1";
button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

Whether that's a good idea or not is a different matter.